# trying to generate a JAX-WS response and getting an exception

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to generate a JAX-WS response and getting the following exception:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>

Could not generate the XML stream caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared     namespace prefix "tns"&#xd;. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [20,26].</faultstring></soap:Fault>
</return>

</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Here's my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://url"
           xmlns:tns="http://url">
  <xs:element name="context" nillable="true" type="tns:context" />
  <xs:complexType name="context">
    <xs:sequence>      
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Recommendations" type="tns:ArrayOfElements" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfElements">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Recommendation" nillable="true" type="tns:Recommendation" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Recommendation">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="item" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Recommendation" nillable="true" type="tns:Recommendation" />
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfRecommendation" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfRecommendation" />
</xs:schema>
```

Any suggestions what could be the reason of this error? I'm using JBoss 6.2 for this JAX-WS

PS. Adding ArrayOfRecommendation:

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfRecommendation">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Recommendation" nillable="true"   type="tns:Recommendation" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Recommendation">
  <xs:sequence>
```

Comment: xml schema above does not have definition of element ArrayOfRecommendation. Plz share that as well. May be you want to use ArrayOfElements instead of  ArrayOfRecommendation?

Comment: Added ArrayOfRecommendation. This schema is autogenerated, so the only problem I see is in namespaces, which I cannot figure out.

Comment: It seems there is no issue in above schema. Plz share your WSDL file.

Comment: Turns out, the application server, JBoss, which served the requests didn't handle ns correctly, in this case, ns:tns was internally converted to ns:a which throws out the inner types from that schema.